# Nextjs, authLink, httpLink and GraphQL subscription issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo-client

Having some issues getting this to play ball. After some digging I did find that nextjs/ssr has issues with subscriptions and you need to first check `process.browser` exists. However I'm now having issues getting my authLink to work with httpLink and splitLink.

Current I have it setup as below, which works fine but authLink is not being used.

```
import {ApolloClient, ApolloLink, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache, split} from "@apollo/client"
import {setContext} from "@apollo/client/link/context"
import { WebSocketLink } from "@apollo/client/link/ws"
import {getMainDefinition} from "@apollo/client/utilities";

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
})

const wsLink = process.browser ? new WebSocketLink({
    uri: 'ws://localhost:4000/graphql',
    options: {
        reconnect: true
    }
}) : null

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: token
        }
    }
})

const splitLink = process.browser ? split(({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query)
    return (
        definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' && definition.operation === 'subscription'
    )
}, wsLink, httpLink) : httpLink

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: splitLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default client;
```

I want to now also include the authLink and have tried to concat or use `ApolloLink` to create the link such as:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([splitLink, authLink]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: You are calling concat on a terminating link, which will have no effect
```

Any suggestions on what else I can try here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Swap the order of the links as follows:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([authLink, splitLink]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

Reference: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/#the-terminating-link